# Why Lord Chaitanya is called "noder nimai"?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, puranas, chaitanya

Why Lord Chaitanya mahaprabhu is called "noder nimai"?

Comment: Lord Chaitanya was called Nimai because he was born under a Neem tree.His mother would call him Nimai. 'Noder' probably in Bengali is related to His birth place Nadia in west Bengal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as I know Noder Nimai was a Bengali movie based on life of Lord Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.

Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's original name was Vishvambhar and was also called Nimai, since he was born under a Neem tree. The offshoot of this tree is still present in Mayapur and this place is called Yog-Pith; the birth place of Lord Chaitanya Mahaprabhu.

Among Sanskrit and Vedic scholars also He began to be known as Nimai Pandit.
Chaitanya Mahaprabhu was born in Mayapur in Nadia district of West Bengal, Hence the name 'Noder Nimai'; meaning 'Nimai of Nadia'.